# OpenCV 3.1.0 NB Classifier classifying all MNIST training samples into single class

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am trying to use OpenCV 3.1.0 to train a NB classifier for the MNIST dataset. I used the prepared CSV training and data file from http://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/ for training the NB classifier. I slightly modified this CSV file using cut and paste to fit the requirements of OpenCV. After training the classifier I tried to use it to classify the training dataset, but it is classifying all samples into class 0. The training dataset has 784 dimensions, 10 classes, and 60000 samples. My training code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    String trainingDataFile(argv[1]);
    Ptr<TrainData> trainingData = TrainData::loadFromCSV(trainingDataFile,0);

    Ptr<NormalBayesClassifier> nbClassifier = NormalBayesClassifier::create();
    nbClassifier->train(trainingData);

    nbClassifier->save(trainingDataFile+"_trainedNBParams.dat");

    return 0;
}
```

The testing code simply reloads the NB classifier from file and classifies all the samples. I used this code successfully for another smaller dataset with 128 dimensions, 10 classes, and 10000 samples. I am unsure if it is a problem with my code, the training method, or OpenCV itself. Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to judge what the problem might be without additional information.

1. OpenCV: As long as you're using a stable version, I doubt the problem is in the openCV library.
2. The Training Method: Especially given that the data is MNIST, I doubt you would have to do any fine tuning to get a reasonable result. Just leaving parameters as default for opencv should be fine. You're methodology also seems sound.
3. My guess is in the data, since that's the only variable that has changed and resulted in the failure. could you try and iterate over the training data

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < trainingData->getSamples().size(); i++) {
       // check contents of data
   }
   ```

   and see if there's anything wrong there? (number of samples, dimensions, etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to get back to you about this till tomorrow. Will do it as soon as I can, though.

Comment: The training data is loaded using the inbuilt loadFromCSV function, and I have checked the size of the samples and responses matrix and can confirm that they are as expected.